# Oracle: 'populate pending' index of another schema

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

When attempting to call `ctx_ddl.populate_pending` on an index of another schema...

```
call ctx_ddl.populate_pending ('OTHERSCHEMA.INDEX_NAME', null);
```

... I'm getting an Oracle error:

```
SQL-Fehler: ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10502: index INDEX_NAME does not exist
```

When I connect as `OTHERSCHEMA` user and execute the same statement, everything works fine.

Why does it tell me the index doesn't exist (it does, verified) here? 
Am I missing any grants or anything else?

*Constraint for proposed solutions: I don't want to have to use 'alter session' as a workaround.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
*Seems to be a bug in Oracle 11.2. With Oracle 12.1, the statement works fine. 
 Treat the solution below as a workaround for Oracle 11.2.*

---

Solved it with a **delegation to a procedure in the target schema**:

On target schema '`OTHERSCHEMA`'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE POPULATE_PENDING_INDEX IS
BEGIN
     execute immediate 'call ctx_ddl.populate_pending(''INDEX_NAME'', NULL)';
END;
/
```

Execute with another schema user:

```
exec OTHERSCHEMA.POPULATE_PENDING_INDEX
```